# How do you test django-axes with a Django unit test?

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django Axes with my Django project to ensure that if someone is trying to guess a password, their IP gets blocked for a while.

It's setup, and works great.

I want to write a Django test that makes sure that after X number of guesses, the user is really locked out.

The problem I'm having is that if you try to use the django test client to do a login as you normally would:

```
self.client.login(username="invalid_user", password="invalid_password")
```

Axes crashes, because it isn't getting a request arg:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/my_project/website/login_app/tests/test_views.py", line 71, in test_brute_force_attempts
    self.client.login(username="invalid_user", password="invalid_password")
  File "/opt/my_project/venv3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 602, in login
    user = authenticate(**credentials)
  File "/opt/my_project/venv3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 73, in authenticate
    user = backend.authenticate(request, **credentials)
  File "/opt/my_project/venv3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/axes/helpers.py", line 411, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/my_project/venv3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/axes/backends.py", line 39, in authenticate
    "AxesBackend requires a request as an argument to authenticate"
axes.exceptions.AxesBackendRequestParameterRequired: AxesBackend requires a request as an argument to authenticate
```

This is a known issue, and is discussed here: https://github.com/jazzband/django-axes/issues/433

As far as I can tell, you just need to pass `self.client.login` a `request=` arg, which it will pass to `django.contrib.auth.authenticate`, and it'll be happy. I can't figure out where to get this `request` within a test method. I tried this, but it didn't work either:

```
class TestBruteForceAttempts(TestCase):
    def test_brute_force_attempts(self):
        login_attempts_to_make = django_settings.AXES_FAILURE_LIMIT + 1 

        for i in range(login_attempts_to_make):
            self.client.login(request=self.client.request(), username="invalid_user", password="invalid_password")
            ...
```

Is there any way to test Django Axes from a Django unit test? I'm clearly doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the [Django Axes documentation](https://django-axes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/3_usage.html#authenticating-users), rather than using `client.login` you can directly call the Django [`authenticate` function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.authenticate) passing a mock request.

Something like this should do the trick:

```py
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from django.http import HttpRequest

class TestBruteForceAttempts(TestCase):
    def test_brute_force_attempts(self):
        login_attempts_to_make = django_settings.AXES_FAILURE_LIMIT + 1

        for i in range(login_attempts_to_make):
            request = HttpRequest()
            authenticate(request, username="invalid_user", password="invalid_password")

        # Assert IP is blocked
```

You probably need to specify some information in the request, for example a fixed IP.

Alternatively, [here](https://github.com/jazzband/django-axes/blob/32e011c7a0b64b6c5d0d88a3fbac271555221c8c/axes/tests/test_login.py#L84) you can see how the test you need is implemented in Django Axes, you could use the same approach.

Comment: `from django.http import HttpRequest()` shouldn't have the brackets, but apparently, this is too small an edit for stackoverflow. Also, `self.client.login` passes all args directly to `django.contrib.auth.authenticate` [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/test/client.py#L594). I tried using a blank `HttpRequest()`, but that didn't seem to work. It didn't crash, but Axes didn't block any attempts either. Looking at the `HttpRequest()` class, it doesn't seem to have a way to set any info (like the IP) when you initialize it - not sure what to do from here.

Comment: I fixed the typo, thanks. The IP is in `request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']`, you might need to replace the full `META` dictionary because, if I remember well, it's read only.

Comment: I've also added a link to the Django Axes repo showing how they implemented the test you need.

Comment: Thanks for the link to their tests. I used that as a staring point and reference to make my own tests that fit my needs. You were right - I just needed to fill the fake request's data with simulated values, which the link showed how to do.